# Socket.IO don't load inside TideSDK app

Tags: javascript, node.js, webkit, socket.io, tidesdk

i created a chat app using Node.JS + Socket.IO + TideSDK, actually my Node.JS+Socket.IO server work perfectly through browser, but when a try load the server with my TideSDK app this error happend:
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: io

What's can be happend?

The code below is how i call the server.

```
<script src="https://mynodeserver.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('https://mynodeserver.com/');
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is probably that https://mynodeserver.com/socket.io/socket.io.js havent been loaded when you call var socket = io.connect(); You should probably wrap it in some kind of document.ready event (document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){var socket = io.connect('https://mynodeserver.com/');}) or similar.

Comment: Thanks Jesper, i will try do this.

Comment: Jesper, you code work in Mac OS, but when i try run the app in Windows, the error appears.

Comment: @Tomazio Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723528/tidesdk-not-working-with-pusher

Comment: @fairwinds when the TideKit will be released?